# Hibernate - <property> values vs. <column> values

Tags: java, hibernate, hbm, hbmxml

I'm back here in Stackoverflow wondering what the difference is between values in  and  within a Hibernate's hbm.xml file.

I explain myself a little better:

```
<property column="LOGIN_NAME" generated="insert" lazy="false" name="loginName" not-null="true" type="java.lang.String" unique="true">
    <column length="128" name="LOGIN_NAME" not-null="true" sql-type="VARCHAR(128)" unique="true"/>
</property>
```

In the above example I repeat some values such as `not-null`, `unique` or `column-name` in both `<property>` and `<column>`. My question(s) is, what's the difference? Which of those must/should be defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no requirement to have both the tags for the same representation. Instead of writing the way you have written above following is the way to write it.

```
<property column="LOGIN_NAME" generated="insert" lazy="false" name="loginName" not-null="true" type="java.lang.String" unique="true" sql-type="VARCHAR(128)" length="128">
</property>
```

The column tag is part of the property tag itself. You only need to define it once. Its not required to add same properties again and again.

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciate the answer!

Comment: Taking advantage of your knowledge... Here is another quick question :)
Is it worth to define the sql-type? Does not this bind the "field" to a specific DB? I mean, `BIT` type for example is exclusive for MySQL...

Comment: It depends on your use case. Generally we do not use sql-type to define column types.